# set variables in ado recordset - VBA

Tags: mysql, vba, variables, ado, recordset

I need to create a progressive balance of some financial operations. I created the variable `SaldoProgr` and I try te sql into my Heidisql and it's ok.

The problem is when I pass the sql to the ado recordset:

```sql
sql = 
"set @SaldoProgr := 0; 
SELECT cvCodLan, cdData, ccMovimento, ccDocto, ccCredito, ccDebito, ROUND((@SaldoProgr := @SaldoProgr + ifnull(ccCredito,0)-ifnull(ccDebito,0)),2) as Saldo
 FROM tbl_FluxoCaixa 
WHERE (cdData Between 'xxxx-xx-xx' And 'xxxx-xx-xx') order by cdData"
```

when I pass this string to a ado recordset it returns error

`gRs` is a `ADODB.Recordset`

```
    With gRs
        Set .ActiveConnection = dbADO
        .Source = sql
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
        .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open
    End With
```

Well, I'd like to know how to create and pass a variable to the ado

tks everyone

Comment: Could you please tell us, _which_ error it throws?

Answer (score 1):

I solved in this way:

```sql
SELECT cvCodLan, cdData,  ccMovimento, ccDocto, ccCredito, ccDebito, 
ROUND((@SaldoProgr := @SaldoProgr + ifnull(ccCredito,0)-ifnull(ccDebito,0)),2) as Saldo 
 FROM tbl_FluxoCaixa  
 JOIN (SELECT @SaldoProgr := 0) R
WHERE (cdData Between 'xxxx-xx-xx' And 'xxxx-xx-xx') order by cdData
```